# can someone please identify this plant for me?

Tags: identification

[image]

Found this plant growing in my garden. Do not know what it is. Can someone please identify?

Comment: Welcome! Please read the [tag info](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) for identification and [edit] your post accordingly. The [tour] and the [help] will explain more about how the site works.

Comment: Where do you live? Continent/region. This will help us. In any case, it is an Asteraceae (composite).

Comment: I live in Bangalore, India

Comment: Please update the question when the flowers show, need colour and shape of flowers; also if you break the main rib of one of the lower leaves does it produce a milky sap?

Comment: Ok, will post update when it flowers. Tried breaking a leaf - it was watery, clear sap.

Comment: It looks like a "wild lettuce" species - possibly Lactuca saligna judging by the leaf shape. The flowers will likely be pale yellow. It is a member of the Asteraceae family. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactuca_saligna

Comment: Ahh, yes, looks like it is a variety of wild lettuce!! Thanks. The flowers haven't bloomed fully yet, but I do see yellow.